# Handle when BLE device is no longer visible

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an iOS app which connects to `Bluetooth Low Energy` device (heart rate monitor) using `CoreBluetooth`. It seems like `CentralManager` delegate doesn't have a method where it handles when a device is no longer visible - it only has methods `didDiscoverPeripheral` and `didRetrievePeripheral`. Moreover, it successfully retrieves (on request) a peripheral which has been disconnected and moved away from the phone.

All I want is to handle when a device is no longer reachable by bluetooth and remove it from the list of available devices. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are currently no built-in options in the `corebluetooth.framework` to handle this case. But if you're just using this list to populate a tableView, i.e. only using it in the foreground, than just run an `NSTimer` to periodically stop and restart discovery. Clear your data array and restart. If it's nearby, you'll still get it. Otherwise you won't. There's definitely some new stuff being added in the `corebluetooth.framework` for the next version of ios though, so let's hope for the best!